# How do I add back a UINavigationItem once I've set it to nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UIBarButton item set as the right button on a UINavigationBar. I also have a UISegmentedControl set as the titleView. These were both added using Interface Builder.

Here is the code I am using to remove the items:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:nil animated:YES];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:nil];
```

The question is, now that I've set them to `nil`, how do I add them back onto the UINavigationBar?

The items are `self.barAdd` and `self.segLibrary`. How can I reload them from the .xib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code similar to the following:

```
- (void) addAddFolderButton
{
    NSMutableArray *rightBarButton = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems];
    [rightBarButton addObject:barAdd];
    [rightBarButton addObject:segLibrary];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:rightBarButton animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Nope, it crashes with: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`

Comment: Your object (barAdd and segLibrary) must be getting deallocated.  Are they ivars so they don't get deallocated once you dereference them?  I use this code all the time.

Comment: I had them set to `weak` instead of `strong`. Setting them to `strong` fixed it. Thanks for the tip!